# Django templates check condition

Tags: python, django, django-templates

If there are are no values in the table how can should the code be to indicate no name found else show the drop down box in the below code

```
  {% for name in dict.names %}
  <option value="{{name.id}}" {% for selected_id in selected_name %}{% ifequal name.id selected_id %} {{ selected }} {% endifequal %} {% endfor %}>{{name.firstname}}</option>{% endfor %} 
   </select>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want `for`...`empty` pair of tags.

```
<select>
    {% for name in dict.names %}
    <option value="{{name.id}}" 
      {% for selected_id in selected_name %}
        {% ifequal name.id selected_id %} {{ selected }} {% endifequal %} 
      {% endfor %}>
      {{name.firstname}}
    </option>
    {% empty %}
    <option value="">No names</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

More details [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)